# Softlayer: Attach detach storage block (endurance) via API

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

How to proceed to attach and detach a storage block endurance to a Virtuel Machine  from the API.

Answer (score 1):

To authorize/allow hosts to a `Network Storage` (i.e. Endurance), please execute:

URL:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/[Storage_id]/allowAccessFromHostList
```

Method: POST

Json Payload:

```
{
  "parameters": [
    [
      {
        "id": 1234567,
        "objectType": "SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Where: `1234567` is the `Virtual Server Instance`

The Above request is used to authorize **“Endurance”** and **“Performance”**.
If you want to authorize **`“Virtual Guest”,“IpAddress” or “Hardware”`**, valid values for `“objectType”` are:
**`“SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest “,”SoftLayer_Network_Subnet_IpAddress”, ”SoftLayer_Hardware”`** respectively.

**Reference:**
[SoftLayer_Network_Storage::allowAccessFromHostList](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/allowAccessFromHostList)

**Note:**
The **“network storage”** and **VSI/Bar Metal/Subnet** must to be located in the same location/datacenter.

These requests help us to get available hosts can be authorized to a specific `“network storage”` as we can see in the Portal:

To get valid **available virtual guests**, please execute:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/[storage_id]/getAllowableVirtualGuests?objectMask=mask[id,fullyQualifiedDomainName] 

Method: GET
```

Reference: [SoftLayer_Network_Storage::getAllowableVirtualGuests](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/getAllowableVirtualGuests)

**Available Bar metal:**

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/[storage_id]/getAllowableHardware
Method: GET
```

Reference: [SoftLayer_Network_Storage::getAllowableHardware](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/getAllowableHardware)

To get valid available **subnets with associated IP addresses**, execute:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/[storage_id]/ getAllowableSubnets?objectMask=mask[id,networkIdentifier,cidr,subnetType,ipAddresses[id,ipAddress]]
Method: GET
```

Reference:
[SoftLayer_Network_Storage::getAllowableSubnets](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/getAllowableSubnets)

Answer (score 1):

Once you ordered the storage you have to follow these steps:

- Authorize the host you want to access to the storage
- Mount the storage to your host

Via API you only can authorize a host from a VSI or bare metal server in order this server has the permission to mount the endurance block storage, but the mount proccess must be manually.

To authorize the block storages via API you use these methods:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/allowAccessFromHostList
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/allowAccessToNetworkStorage
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/allowAccessToNetworkStorage

To mount the storage see these documentation:
https://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/procedure/accessing-block-storage-linux
https://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/procedure/accessing-block-storage-microsoft-windows
https://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/procedure/accessing-file-storage-linux
https://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/content/ordering-and-configuring-endurance-and-performance-block-storage-vmwaresoftlayer
https://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/procedure/endurance-provisioning

Regards